# Can't get my input to be displayed on .txt file

Tags: c++, c++11

I have the user input a list of names (getNames) and then write those names to a chosen txt file. I'm trying to get the names to be displayed on the text file but nothing is working. I've tried many different things but can't figure it out.

The getFile function is right at the beginning. I need to have 'fout' display the names the user has entered. How do I get the .txt to display the names the user has entered from getNames?

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;
char getMenu(); // list of functions
int getNames(vector<string>& v);
void displayNames(vector<string>& v);
void sortNames(vector<string>& v);
int findName(vector<string>& v, string name);
void removeNames(vector<string>& v, string name);
void getFile(vector<string>& v);

void getFile(vector<string>& v)
{
    string fileName;        
    cout << "Enter file name: ";
    getline(cin, fileName);
    ofstream fout(fileName.c_str(),ios::app);
    fout << ""; **// need to display names here**
    fout.close();

}

char getMenu() 
{
    char letter;  
         cout << "(G)etNames, (D)isplayNames, (S)ortNames, (R)emoveNames, (F)indNames," << endl << "(W)rite to file, (Q)uit:" << endl;      
    cin >> letter;  
    cin.ignore(256, '\n'); // cleans upto 256 characters
    return toupper(letter); //toupper makes lowercase=uppercase
}

int main() 
{ 
  vector<string> v; 
  string name; 

  bool quit = true;

  do
  {
    switch(getMenu())
    {
      case 'G': getNames(v); break; 
      case 'S': sortNames(v); cout << endl << "Sorted names:" << endl;
                displayNames(v); break;
      case 'D': displayNames(v); break;
      case 'F': findName(v, name); break;
      case 'R': removeNames(v, name); break;
      case 'W': getFile(v); break;
      case 'Q': quit = false; break;
      default: "Error. Try again: "; cout << endl; break;
    } 

  }
  while(quit);
  cout << endl << "Program terminated." << endl;

}


int getNames(vector<string>& v)
{
    string tmp; // gets names
    while(true) 
    {
        cout<<"Enter a name, quit to stop:";
        cin>>tmp;
        if(tmp=="quit")
        {
            break;
        }
        v.push_back(tmp);
    }
}

void displayNames(vector<string>& v)
{
    for(int i=0; i<v.size(); i++) // displays names
    {
        cout<<v.at(i)<<endl;
    }
}

void sortNames(vector<string>& v) // sort names
{
  sort(v.begin(),v.end()); 
}

int findName(vector<string>& v, string name)
{
    cout << "Enter name to find : " << endl;
    cin >> name;
    int pos = find(v.begin(), v.end(), name) - v.begin();
        if (pos<v.size())
    {
    cout << "The name, " << name << ", was found." << endl;
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "Name not found." << endl;
    }    
}

void removeNames(vector<string>& v, string name)    
{{
    string name;
    if(v.size() > 0) 
    {    
    cout << "Enter name to remove: " << endl;
    }
    cin >> name;

    int pos = find(v.begin(), v.end(), name) - v.begin();
    if (pos >= 0)    

    {
      v.erase(v.begin() + pos); //goes to 
                                //(first value + the position) and erases       
      cout << name << " has been removed." << endl; 
    }
    else
    {
      cout << "That name does not exits." << endl;
    }


    }}
```

Comment: `getFile` should be similar to `displayNames`. `std::cout` is an output stream as `std::ofstream`.

Comment: You can iterate over the elements of the vector, if that is what you want. What do you mean exactly with "Display the names"? Can you give an example, what worked, and what did not?

Comment: I want have the names that I have entered be displayed in the txt 
e.g
Tom, John, Mike, etc.

@arc_lupus

Comment: displayed \equiv written? Use the answer shown below...

Comment: perfect, it worked @arc_lupus
Just need to understand what it means now hah

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simplest solution seems to be:

```
for(auto& name : v)
    fout << name << '\n';
```

I am not sure how they should be separated, though.